# При запуске приложения на физическом носителе с андроид 4.1 приложение крашится, в чём может быть дело?

Tags: java, android

Запускаю приложение на андроид 10 и 8.1, всё нормально, приложение работает хорошо.
Как только ставлю на 4.1 или же 5.1, сразу же крашится, в чём может быть дело? В логах, указывается, что ошибка обнаружена в методе onCreate, со строкой `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
Вот логи:

```
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 247 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f07008c (t=6 e=140) in package 0 (error -75) name=ru.geokrasnodar.gk_tracker
    Failure getting entry for 0x7f07008c (t=6 e=140) in package 0 (error -75) name=ru.geokrasnodar.gk_tracker
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ccc600)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.geokrasnodar.gk_tracker/ru.geokrasnodar.gk_tracker.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #114: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2355)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1353)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5578)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #114: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at ru.geokrasnodar.gk_tracker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:67)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1102)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1353) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5578) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07008c
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1024)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getValue(ResourcesWrapper.java:214)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.loadDrawableFromDelegates(ResourceManagerInternal.java:252)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:139)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:63)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:82)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:69)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:199)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:119)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1551)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1602)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
        at ru.geokrasnodar.gk_tracker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:67) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1102) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1353) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5578) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
D/Process: killProcess, pid=3334
D/Process: dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
    java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
    android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:956)
    com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:108)
    androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$1.uncaughtException(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:177)
    java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
    java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Поправка: само приложение занимает крайне мало места в памяти.

Comment: У вас чего-то в ресурсах не хватает. Это видно из вашего лога: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07008c`. Смотрите какие в разметке ресурсы использованы и в каких папках они лежат. Видимо что-то из них лежит в чём-то типа `value-26`, например, а в `values` этого нет.

Comment: Как минимум из приведенного лога есть подозрение, что Вы используете RippleDrawable в одном из своих ресурсов. Данный класс появился только с андроида 5.0. Соответственно, на 5 андроиде ошибка скорее всего другая.

Comment: Да, так и есть, ошибка была связана с rippleDrawable, из-за чего приложение и крашилось. Спасибо)